# Hover, увеличение области действия

Tags: css

Нужна помощь. есть 2 блока: 1 видимый, 2 невидимый.

Наводим на видимый > появляется невидимый. Скрин приложил. Мне нужно чтоб 2ой блок оставался пока курсор не "уедет". Ибо на 2ом блоке есть ссылки на фейсбук, твиттер и т.п

```
.reiss-ramka {
        visibility:  hidden;
        display:block;
        width: 216px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: #00a388;
        margin-top: -67px;
        ;
    }
.about-REISS-SOMERS:hover  > .reiss-ramka {
        visibility: visible;
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Простое решение - сделать 2ой блок по размеру области (имеется ввиду расширить "рамку области" вокруг контента до тех пор, пока размеры не совпадут с областью 1. Ну и сделать тоже самое правило с ховер на блок 2.

Comment: Уже задавал этот вопрос! Прикрепляй html на будущее!
Все же элементарно, если хотя бы основы css почитать! Что бы не исчезал блок с иконками и на него же вешай :hover! + Начни наконец-то проверять свои стили на ошибки!!! `.about-REISS-SOMERS:hover  > .reiss-ramka, .reiss-ramka:hover {
        visibility: visible;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать блок, в который поместить оба элемента (видимый и невидимый) и уже при наведении на него показывать второй. Кстати, такой подход заодно и семантически более верный, так как объединяет контент по смыслу.

```css
article {
  border: solid;
}

article:hover .secondary {
  display: block;
}

.main {
  background: green;
  height: 100px;
}

.secondary {
  background: ivory;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
}

a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
  <article>
    <div class="main">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/400/100" />
    </div>
    
    <div class="secondary">
      <a href="#"> link </a>
      <a href="#"> link </a>
      <a href="#"> link </a>
      <a href="#"> link </a>
    </div>
  </article>
```